# ShowInTaskbar not working reliably in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a modal window in WPF and for this window `ShowInTaskbar` is set to true but application icon is not showing in taskbar every time for this model window. Sometimes the icon shows up in taskbar and sometimes it does not. But the requirement is application icon should always be visible in the taskbar when this modal window (using `ShowDialog`) is launched.
window Style is set as : `ThreeDBorderWindow`

Code to show modal window is :

```
 winIHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(_shell);                                                  
                    _shell.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
                    winIHelper.Owner = parentHandle;                                          
                    _shell.ShowInTaskbar = true;
                    _shell.Activate();                        
                    _shell.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: have you set owner ?

Comment: check the window style : toolwindow?

Comment: what have you tried? add the respective segments of code to your question, then it's much easier to tell you what goes wrong and where

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you ever figure out what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar case where `ShowInTaskbar` was not working correctly when a different window (Splash screen in my case) was shown without setting any Owner.

So, settings the `Owner` property of the **Other** window - solved my case.

Comment: What did you set the Other window owner property to?